# Loop through URLs using BeautifulSoup, and either RegEx or Lambda, to do matching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, lambda, beautifulsoup

I am trying to loop through a few URLs and scrape out one specific class.  I believe it's called:

```
<div class="Fw(b) Fl(end)--m Fz(s) C($primaryColor" data-reactid="192">Overvalued</div>
```

Here is the URL:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/goog

Here is the data that I want for GOOG.

```
Near Fair Value
```

I believe this will require some kind of Lambda function or RegEx.  I tried to do this without using these methodologies, but I couldn't get it working.  Here is the code that I am testing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

mylink = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
mylist = ['SBUX', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']
mystocks = []

html = requests.get(mylink).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

#details = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('Fw(b) Fl(end)--m')})

details = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : re.compile('Fw(b)*')})
for item in mylist:
    for r in details:
        mystocks.append(item + ' - ' + details)

print(mystocks)
```

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

After the code runs, I would like to see something like this.

```
GOOG - Near Fair Value
SBUX - Near Fair Value
MSFT - Overvalued
```

The problem is, that if I use something like this:  `'Fw(b)*'`, I get too much data pulled back.  If I try to expand that, to this: `'Fw(b) Fl(end)--m Fz(s)'`, I get nothing back.  How can I get the results I showed above?

Comment: I cant find the class you are looking for `Fw(b) Fl(end)--m Fz(s) C($primaryColor` in the page source

Comment: Is it because the markets are closed?

Comment: I just added a screen shot to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use regex, CSS selector is enough. The key is to use correct HTTP header - `User-Agent`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [('GOOG', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/goog'),
        ('SBUX', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/sbux'),
        ('MSFT', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/msft')]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

for q, url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    value = soup.select_one('div:contains("XX.XX") + div').text

    print('{:<10}{}'.format(q, value))
```

Prints:

```
GOOG      Near Fair Value
SBUX      Near Fair Value
MSFT      Overvalued
```

Comment: Both work fine.  I never really understood the 'Mozilla' thing.  I guess that will be my next thing to learn!  Thanks to both of you!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the html being returned from your `requests` get-request and from a request in Broswer, e.g `view-source:https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/goog` are different. The div that has your target class is missing when you visit the page using python. I found that out by printing the html from `requests` and comparing with the browser html.

Here are the suggested steps to take:

1. Append the link ending to each url by looping through `mylist`
2. The Yahoo server detects that you are a robot by reading your request's headers and limits some information. You need to add relevant headers to disguise your request.
3. I suspect that the yahoo server is only reading your `user-agent` but I'll leave that for you to experiment; and its good for me to post the full headers here for reference purposes.

The headers can be got from the chrome dev-tools, in the network tab.
Trillworks [Online tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/) shows how to do so and helps you convert them to requests code.

Proposed solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mylink = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
mylist = ['SBUX', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']
mystocks = []

headers = {
    'authority': 'finance.yahoo.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'dnt': '1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,ar-EG;q=0.6,ar;q=0.5,my-ZG;q=0.4,my;q=0.3',

    'cookie': '', # Note: I removed the cookie value, it was too long
}

for item in mylist:
    html = requests.get(mylink + item, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    details = soup.find('div', class_="Fw(b) Fl(end)--m Fz(s) C($primaryColor")
    mystocks.append(item + ' - ' + details.text)

print(mystocks)
```

This prints:

```
GOOG - Near Fair Value
SBUX - Near Fair Value
MSFT - Overvalued
```